# manage.py cant find any urls in myapp.urls file. Says something about circular import

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I seem to find the following error despite making a number of changes in my app.urls file and in my project.urls file. I can't seem to put my finger on it, here is the code:

app.urls file

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home_page, name = 'home_page'),

]
```

project.urls file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('Success.urls')),
]
```

views.py file

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

```
enter code here
```

## Create your views here.

```
def home_page(request):
  hello = 'hello world'
  return HttpResponse (hello)
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added your app in the settings.py file?

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'Success',
]
```

Comment: Yes i have added my app name to the settings.py file

Comment: Can you post the error that you are getting?

Comment: raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '<module 'Success.urls' from 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\NewApp\\NewWorld\\Success\\urls.py'>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.

Comment: I have created the a project same as you, on my end it works properly, just check if your app is created properly, try and delete the project and recreate it, check if the urls file in app is named properly,

Answer (score 0):

i imported render and used it instead i can't figure out though why it worked

views.py file
from django.shortcuts import render
def hello_world(request):
return render(request, 'hello_world.html')

app/urls.py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

```
    urlpatterns = [
      path('', views.hello_world, name = 'hello_world')
    ]
```

project/urls.py

```
    from django.contribs import admin
    from django.urls import path, include
    urlpatterns = [
      path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
      path('', include('app.urls'))
    ]
```